# Manipulation axes in plot

Tags: plotting, ticks, graphics

If I have the following,

```
    DensityPlot[x Sin[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

and the output is

[image]

is there any way I can change the axes ticks. let's say 2 to 4 and 4 to 6, without changing the
x and y range in the code `x Sin[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}`. By only using axes command such as changing axes on the existing output `Axes -> 2 to 4 and 4 to 6`.

Comment: **is there any way I can change the axes ticks. let's say 2 to 4 and 4 to 6, without changing the x and y range in the code** not clear what you mean, since the labels already show `2,4`. But you can always play with the option `Ticks -> {Range[-5, 5, 1], Automatic}` and change the labels any way you want. see help on `Ticks`

Comment: Study the helpfile on `Ticks`. You can place any label at any value with `Ticks->{{{xvalue,xlabel},...},{{yvalue,ylabel},...}}`. Two lists of pairs of values and labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DensityPlot[x Sin[y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, Frame -> False, 
 Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Ticks -> {{{-4, -6}, {-2, -4}, {2, 4}, {4, 
     6}}, {{-4, -6}, {-2, -4}, {2, 4}, {4, 6}}}]
```

[image]